# Importing MySQL JDBC driver in lift

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, lift, dependency-management

I'm trying to establish a database connection in my lift app using the mysql jdbc driver. I included the jar file in the eclipse build path, but building with importing the jar using `import com.mysql._`the app with sbt always throws the error:

> object mysql is not a member of package com

Setting the classpath in the sdb.bat didn't help neither setting the system classpath variable.

```
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
java -Dscala.userjavacp=true -cp "%SCRIPT_DIR%\src\main\java\mysql.jar" -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024M -Xss2M -jar "%SCRIPT_DIR%\sbt-launch-0.12.1.jar" %*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBT doesn't know anything about Eclipse build path. You need to add dependencies in [the way SBT understands](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies), e.g.:

> add jars to `lib` and they will be placed on the project classpath. Not much else to it!

Comment: Hmm, guess thats my problem. I'm running a companies Windows XP machine without many privileges in the system directories

Comment: It isn't a system directory, it's the `lib` subdirectory of your project.

Comment: Ok, it coudn't work. My build.sbt did not contain the unmanaged Jar directory

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [SBT Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki) and then use SBT to manage your dependencies which should keep the two programs in sync.

So, for MySQL, you'd want to modify your sbt configuration in your project to include:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.6"
```

Then all you would need to do is launch sbt, and type `eclipse` to update your Eclipse configuration files with the correct classpath. When you restart Eclipse, everything should work.

The plugin will also pick up files in the lib directory as noted in the other answer.